# Populate a html drop down box (<select>) with data from a google sheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have created this website with google that is hosted in my google drive https://sites.google.com/view/cryptocurrencyman/home

Now, on the page Crypto Currency Charts I want a dropdown box with all the available crypto currencies from the google sheet that is available on the page Crypto Currency Data so the visitor can select which crypto currency they want to plot the historical price for.

I get the names of all the crypto currencies in column 1 in that that google sheet by running the following google app script function. This is the data I want in the drop down box.

```
function Get() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...........").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow);
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  Logger.log("Data = " + data); 

  return data;
 };
```

This is the html code for a simple drop down box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <form>
        Select the value of y: &nbsp;    
          <select id="s1"> 
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
         </select>
     </form>
 </html>
```

This is where the problem starts. How can I create a HTML drop down box  with all the available crypto currencies in column1 from that specific google sheet with data? I dont want to manually enter all the names into the above html table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do this?  This is the easy part.

HTML_Test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mySelectList">
    </select>
    <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (selectList) {
            var select = document.getElementById("mySelectList");
            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.text = selectList[i][0];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).getSelectList();
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Codes.gs

```
function getSelectList() {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    return values;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will study your provided code closely and see what I can learn from it.

Comment: When I run your provided google app function I get an error message: "[19-02-18 18:49:02:476 CET] Exception: The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid." even when I have the spreadsheet open in the browser. But I have managed to get the code working anyway by replacing your function code with my function code but with your function name.

Comment: function getSelectList() 
 {
         var sheet =        SpreadsheetApp.openById("....").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow);
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  Logger.log("Data = " + data); 

  return data;
 };

Answer (score 0):

These are the two google sheet functions I got it working with plus the above HTML code:

```
function getSelectList() 
         {
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(".....").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
          var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
          var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow);
          var data = myRange.getValues();
          Logger.log("Data = " + data); 
          return data;
         };


         function doGet() 
         {
         return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_Test');
         }
```